# Derivative of $c^TX^TXc$ with respect to $X$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $c^TX^TXc$ with respect to $X$? Here, all the entries are real and $X$ is a matrix while $c$ is a vector.

I keep getting confused with the left and right multiplication. Hence, if I have these answers in both these angles, I might remember this better, based on the simple one or two line approach you would take.

The following shows these results in the appendix of a book:
\begin{gather*}
\nabla _X a^T X^T X a = 2X a a^T\\
\nabla _X a^T X X^T a = 2 a a^T X
\end{gather*}

Let me know how we get there.

Comment: i) what is your definition of derivative w.r.t. a matrix? usually the gradient w.r.t. a vector $x$ is considered to be a 'one form' (a scalar-valued linear function), i.e. it has the dimensions of $x^\top$, etc (so the answer would be $2cc^TX$)

Comment: ii) likewise, that would be the map $Y\mapsto c^\top X^\top Y c$

Comment: What is $Y$? I did not mention any $Y$. Also page 679, in https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/matrixcalc.pdf says it the other way around as $2Xcc^T$. Who is correct- you, or the book?

Comment: you deleted that part of the question anyway, but probably your book uses the transpose definition. as for the other remark, we can talk about a function $x\mapsto f(x)$ where $x$ is not a previously defined variable; it is then a 'dummy' variable and what we're really interested in is $f$ and it's action on any $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go back to the definition of derivative. Let $F : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be given by $$F(X) = Xcc^T X^T.$$ Fix $X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Then for any $h \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
 F(X+h) = (X+h)cc^T(X+h)^T = Xcc^T X + h cc^T X^T + X cc^T h^T + h cc^T h^T,
$$
which is to say that in terms of your favourite matrix norm,
$$
 F(X+h) = F(X) + (h cc^T X^T + X cc^T h^T) + o(\|h\|).
$$
Thus, by definition, the derivative $DF(X) : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ of $F$ at $X$ is
$$
 DF(X)(h) = h cc^T X^T + X cc^T h^T.
$$
Note the importance of the order of multiplication!

In the same way, let $f : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$
 f(X) = c^T X^T X c.
$$
Fix $X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Then for any $h \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
 f(X+h) = c^T (X+h)^T (X+h) c = c^T X^T X c + c^T h^T X c + c^T X^T h c + c^T h^T h c,
$$
so that
$$
 f(X+h) = f(X) + (c^T h^T X c + c^T X^T h c) + o(\|h\|),
$$
and hence
$$
 Df(X)(h) = c^T h^T X c + c^T X^T h c = 2 c^T X^T h c,
$$
where we used the fact that $c^T h^T X c$ is a scalar, so that
$$
 c^T h^T X c = (c^T h^T X c)^T = c^T X^T h c.
$$

Now, in the case of $f : M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, if we view $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ as an inner product space with inner product $\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr} \langle X,Y\rangle = \Tr(X^T Y)$, then $\nabla f (X)$ is the unique matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that 
$$
 \forall h \in M_n(\mathbb{R}), \quad Df(X)(h) = \langle \nabla f(x),h\rangle := \Tr((\nabla f(x))^T h).
$$
Now, let $C$ be the matrix with first column $c$ and everything else $0$. Check, then, that
$$
 Df(X)(h) = 2 c^T X^T h c = \Tr(2 C^T X^T h C) = \Tr(2 C C^T X^T h) = \langle 2 X C C^T, h\rangle,
$$
so that once you convince yourself that $C C^T = c c^T$,
$$
 \nabla f(X) = 2 X C C^T = 2 X c c^T.
$$

Comment: I have added an image from my book, to the above question. These results don't match yours..please let me know your thoughts. That said, thanks for the clear and elegant explanation as of till now as for exampe it says in the second case that the derivative is $2Xcc^T$ instead .

Comment: @halms Is your first function a typo, then? Because $Xcc^T X^T$ isn't a scalar, so taking the gradient of $X \mapsto Xcc^T X^T$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: oops..yes! corrected it. please focus on the second question (now-only existing question) onto what the book says, and the reasoning for it. I am trying to use this derivative in a larger calculation, but was not sure at how the appendix in the book arrived at it.

Comment: there's another typo: 'Fix $X \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Then for any $X$...'

Answer (score 3):

You can do both questions simultaneously, as each of these functions is of the form $X\longmapsto F(X,X)$ for some $F$ bilinear continuous.

> **Fact:** If $(X,Y)\longmapsto F(X,Y)$ is bilinear and continuous in the sense that there exists $M>0$ such that $\|F(X,Y)\|\leq M \|X\|\|Y\|$, then $F$ is differentiable with derivative
>   $$
> dF_{(X,Y)}(H,K)=F(X,K)+F(H,Y).
> $$

**Proof:** the map $\theta:(H,K)\longmapsto F(X,K)+F(H,Y)$ is linear and continuous. Now
$$
\|F(X+H,Y+K)-F(X,Y)-\theta(H,K)\|=\|F(H,K)\|\leq M\|H\|\|K\|\leq M (\|H\|^2+\|K\|^2).
$$
So
$$
\lim_{(H,K)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{F(X+H,Y+K)-F(X,Y)-\theta(H,K)}{\sqrt{\|H\|^2+\|K\|^2}}=0.
$$
This proves, by definition, that $\theta$ is the derivative of $F$ at $(X,Y)$. QED.

> **Consequence:** with a bilinear continuous function $F$, the compostion $G(X):=F(X,X)$ si differentiable with derivative
>   $$
> dG_{X}(H)=F(X,H)+F(H,X).
> $$

**Proof:** chain rule, given that the derivative of the linear continuous map $\theta(X)=(X,X)$ is $\theta$ at every $X$. QED.

**Application:** note that everything is continuous since we are in finite dimension.

> 1. With the function $F_1(X,Y)=Xcc^TY^T\;$, we get $G_1(X)=Xcc^TX^T$. Hence
>      $$
>    dG_{1_{X}}(H)=F_1(X,H)+F_1(H,X)=Xcc^TH^T+Hcc^TX^T.
>    $$
> 2. With the function $F_2(X,Y)=c^TX^TYc\;$, we get $G_2(X)=c^TX^TXc$. Hence
>      $$
>    dG_{2_{X}}(H)=F_2(X,H)+F_2(H,X)=c^TX^THc+c^TH^TXc.
>    $$

Now to find the gradient and turn the answer into the form of the book, observe, e.g. for the second one, that
$$
c^TX^THc=c^TH^TXc=\mbox{real number}=\mbox{Trace}(c^TX^THc)=\mbox{Trace}((Xcc^T)^TH)
$$
hence
$$
\nabla_X(c^TX^TXc)=2Xcc^T.
$$